# Access parent object property from nested object?

Tags: php

Lets say I have two objects that nest into a parent class:

```
class A {

    public function create() {
        //... create something
    }
}

class B {

    public function getFooter() {
        // I need to access object A function create() here?
    }
}

class C {
    protected $oA;
    protected $oB;

    function __construct() {
        $this->oA = new A();
        $this->oB = new B();
    }
}

$oC = new C();
$oC->oB->getFooter();
```

Is it possible for class B to get to class A via class C?

### EDIT

I forget to mention that I call the functions of class B dynamically ,like this: {*function name here*}(), and thus cannot control the properties that are available as parameters in the functions.

---

**Context:**

I need to store multiple objects into a container class, and I have a class that contains a lot of template functions. For performance reasons, I want to only create one instance of this template class and put it into the container class instead of in multiple subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, class B would need a pointer to the instance of class C (you could pass that into the constructor when you create B). Then class C would need a method that exposes access to the instance of class A.

In B:

```
$A = $this->C->getA();
$A->runsomemethod();
```

In C:

```
public function getA()
{
    return $this->A;
}
```

Comment: So you can access the parent by using the following function in B? 
public function getFooter() {   $this->{parent name} )

Comment: Exactly. There are a bunch of different ways you could do it. You could do $parent->run_some_method_on_A() if you don't want to hold a reference to A directly in B.  Just pass the reference to C to B when you create B.

Comment: I have tried this, but it seems to slow my performance way down... Does the object get duplicated here?

Comment: There shouldn't be any noticeable performance hit for using that technique, objects are passed by reference in PHP by default.